# specs2 skip test based on condition without an exception

Tags: specs2

Is there a way to skip a test in specs2 without the SkippedException occurring? I'd like the test to be ignored under a certain condition so that it doesn't show as error but as ignored.
For example: I have the following in the test/scala/Skipped.scala file

```
package models

import org.specs2.mutable._
import org.specs2.runner._

class Skipped extends Specification{
  "Application" should {
    if( 3 < 2 ){
      "do better with regex" in {

        "axbcd" must find( "bc".r )
      }
    }
    else skipped( "blah" )
  }
}
```

and the following the my build.sbt

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

libraryDependencies += "org.specs2" % "specs2_2.10" % "2.1.1" % "test"
```

When I run the test, I get the following:

```
org.specs2.execute.SkipException: blah
at org.specs2.matcher.ThrownExpectations$class.skipped(ThrownExpectations.scala:87)
```

Am I missing something?

Bonus question:
Why am I using such an old version? When I have the following in my build.sbt, I cannot compile the above code snippet.

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "2.3.12" % "test"
```

The error is:

```
Skipped.scala:7: overloaded method value should with alternatives:
[error]   (fs: => Unit)(implicit p1: Skipped.this.ImplicitParam1, implicit p2: Skipped.this.ImplicitParam2)org.specs2.specification.Fragments <and>
[error]   (fs: => org.specs2.specification.Fragments)(implicit p: Skipped.this.ImplicitParam)org.specs2.specification.Fragments <and>
[error]   (fs: => org.specs2.specification.Fragment)org.specs2.specification.Fragments
[error]  cannot be applied to (Product with Serializable)
[error]   "Application" should {
[error]                 ^
[error] one error found
```

So I'd appreciate if someone could help me with a way to skip a test without an exception, which preferably works in with the newer versions of specs2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
class Skipped extends Specification{
   "Application" should {
     if( 3 < 2 ){
       "do better with regex" in {
         "axbcd" must find( "bc".r )
       }
     }
     else "3 is >= 2" in skipped( "blah" )
   }
}
```

The difference is that `skipped` is declared in the body of an example which allows it to be reported to the console:

```
[info] o 3 is >= 2
[info]    SKIPPED blah
```

(or something like that, I didn't run the code)